# gdcm2vtk usage to convert a stack of images into a vti file

Tags: vtk, gdcm

I've managed to compile GDCM with VTK and I have a particular application I would like to use, which is the "gdcm2vtk.exe".

Now, how's the syntax for converting a stack of imags into a ".vti" file? so far I have this:

```
gdcm2vtk Input_Directory file.vti
```

Now, when I run somthing like this:
gdcm2vtk "C:/dicom/dicom directory" output.vti I get an error:
could not find no reader to handle file: "C:/dicom/dicom directory"

Is there anything I'm missing there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gdcmimg to convert stack of DICOM images into a vti file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367002/gdcmimg-to-convert-stack-of-dicom-images-into-a-vti-file)

Answer (score 0):

`gdcm2vtk` does not handle a directory as input as specified in the [documentation](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcm2vtk.html).

You may want to convert your DICOM Series into a single DICOM Instance using [gdcmimg](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmimg.html#multiple_files)

---

As of GDCM 2.6 `gdcm2vtk` is now able to take as input a directory. Pay attention to sort the file according to the well known Image Orientation (Patient) & Image Position (Patient) strategy instead of relying on the filenames ordering to reconstruct your VTK (*.vti) file:

```
$ gdcm2vtk --ipp-sort input_dir output.vti
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. Now, if I convert my Series into a single DICOM Instance, will I be able to render it as 3D?